# Find $\int \frac{{\rm d}x}{1+e\cos x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

> Find $$\int \frac{{\rm d}x}{1+e\cos x}$$
>
> 1. When $e$ lies between $0$ and $1$
> 2. When $e$ is greater than $1$

---

I got $\int \frac{dx}{1+e\cos x}$ when $e$ lies between $0$ and $1$, by substituting $\tan\frac{x}{2} =t$.

$$\int \frac{dx}{1+e\cos x} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{1-e^2}} \tan^{-1}\left( \frac{\sqrt{1-e}}{\sqrt{1+e}}\tan \frac{x}{2} \right) +C,$$

which will not be valid for $e >1.$

What different attempt we can do for $e>1$?

Comment: Here, $e$ does not necessarily mean the number $2.718281828459045...$. If it means what it usually means, then clearly the $e>1$ case would apply.

Comment: You can use $i\arctan(ia\tan(z))=\text{artanh}(a\tanh(z))$ !

Comment: I have a doubt... If e lies between 0 and 1, then can I write e as cos x or sin X ?

Comment: e is not a variable.. a constant,  but not equal to 2.718281...

Comment: e is probably the eccentricity. This is probably the polar equation of an ellipse with perihelion 1 for e<1

Answer (score 2):

Substituting $t=\tan(\frac{x}{2})$ we obtain for $e\neq1$ (and the case $e=1$ gives $\int \frac{dx}{1+\cos x}=\tan(\frac{x}{2})+c_1$)

$$\int \frac{dx}{1+e\cos x}=\int \frac{2}{1+t^2+e(1-t^2)}dt$$
$$=\int\frac{2}{t^2(1-e)+(1+e)}dt=\int\frac{2}{(1-e)\left(t^2+\frac{1+e}{1-e}\right)}dt=\frac{2}{1-e}\int\frac{1}{t^2+\frac{1+e}{1-e}}dt$$

$\bullet$ Then for $0<e<1$ you can use the $\tan$ substitution to obtain $\arctan$ function (as you did).

$\bullet$ For $e>1$, you can use partial fractions decomposition to obtain logarithms. To make the calculations simpler, you can let $c^2=-\frac{1+e}{1-e}$, then you have $\int\frac{1}{t^2-c^2}dt$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
& \int \frac{dx}{1+e\cos x} = \int \frac{\frac{2\,dt}{1+t^2}}{1+e\cdot\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}} \\[8pt]
= {} & \int \frac{2\,dt}{(1+t^2) + e(1-t^2)} \\[8pt]
= {} & \int \frac{2\,dt}{(1+e) + (1-e)t^2} \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac 1 {1+e} \int \frac{dt}{1 + \frac{1-e}{1+e}\cdot t^2} \\[8pt]
& \text{Then if } e<1 \text{ we get this:} \\
= {} & \frac 1 {(1+e)\sqrt A} \int \frac{\sqrt A\,dt}{1+At^2}
\text{ where } A = \frac{1-e}{1+e} \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac 1 {(1+e)\sqrt A} \int \frac{du}{1+u^2} \text{ and so on.} \\[8pt]
& \text{If } e>1 \text{ then we have} \\[8pt]
& \frac 1 {1+e} \int \frac{dt}{1 - Bt^2} \text{ where } B=-A \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac 1 {1+e} \int \frac{dt}{(1 - t\sqrt B)(1 + t\sqrt B)} \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac 1 {1+e} \int \left( \frac C {1-t\sqrt B} + \frac D{1+t\sqrt B} \right) \, dt \\
& \text{and then you have to do} \\
& \text{some algebra to find $C$ and $D$.}
\end{align}